# How do I cancel a create or edit via a button on the form?

Tags: laravel

I am writing a prototype in Laravel 9. x that, at least so far, is primarily CRUDs for each of several tables. For each table, I have the standard methods in that table's controller: index, show, create, store, edit, update and destroy. All of those work, but I'd like to add Cancel options to the forms used for creating and editing a row in the table.

I'm struggling with how to make a Cancel option work. I was trying to do it by having the Cancel button in the Create form invoke a new method in Controller called cancelCreate; all it would do was redirect to the index view and create a session message indicating that the create had been canceled. Much to my surprise, I found that even when I pressed the Cancel button, the controller's regular create() method would be executed. The create() method insisted that all validations be successful, stored the new record, reported the successful creation, and then displayed the new record in the index view. This was the exact opposite of what a Cancel button should do.

So how do I write my code so that the Cancel button lets the user exit the Create screen regardless of what he has put in the form (or omitted from the form) and return to the Index view WITHOUT having made any change to the table? The course I took on writing CRUDs didn't include Cancel functionality. I can't find any videos about Laravel discussing Cancel functionality, and a search here at StackOverflow didn't bring up anything relevant.

Here is my Create blade so that you can see what I attempted:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-card xclass="p-10 max-w-lg mx-auto mt-24">
    <h1 class="text-3xl text-center text-white font-bold bg-indigo-700">Create a New Non-driving Reason</h1>
    <h1 class="pb-5"></h1><!-- spacer beneath title -->
    
    <form method="POST" action="/nonDrivingReasons/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <div class="mb-6">
            <label for="reason_for_not_driving" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Reason for not driving</label>
            <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="reason_for_not_driving" value="{{old('reason_for_not_driving')}}"/>
            @error('reason_for_not_driving')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
            @enderror
        </div>            
        <div class="mb-6">
            {{-- Submit the completed form --}}
            <button class="text-xl text-white bg-green-500 rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black">Submit</button>
            {{-- Cancel submission of the form --}}
            <form method="POST" action="/nonDrivingReasons/cancelCreate/">
                <button class="text-xl text-black bg-white rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-grey-500">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </x-card>
    </x-layout>
```

And here are the create() and cancelCreate() methods from my Controller:

```
 //Show create the form
    public function create() {
        return view('nonDrivingReasons.create');
    }

    //Cancel creation of a new non-driving reason
    public function cancelCreate() {
        return redirect('/nonDrivingReasons/index')->with('message', 'Creation of non-driving reason cancelled');
    }
```

The table in question is as simple as it gets with just a single column.

I'd be grateful for guidance on building Cancel functionality into my prototype.

Comment: you can't have nested forms and `button` has a `form` attribute

Comment: @lagbox - Fair enough. So how do I cancel my form without having a nested form?

Comment: Interesting. So, do you want to really store the data user sent and then be able to cancel it anytime? Or you just want to display what user is trying to do `before` the actual editing of the database, so user could confirm or cancel the current action? Do you also want to revert `delete` action?

Comment: I've read the question two more times. So you want just to go out of the page? It's not about CRUD or anything and you don't need a controller or form for that, why don't you just use a link? Like `<a href="/"><button>Cancel</button></a>`

Comment: @Lothric - Thank you, your solution works too. I suppose I was making the problem more complicated than it was. I just assumed I'd have to do something that was more "Laravel-ish" than what you and Karl suggested ;-)