# How can I set a session variable conditionally in a blade template?

Tags: laravel

I am developing an app in Laravel 9 and am trying to add Cancel functionality to my Create template. I want the form to have two buttons: Submit and Cancel. I asked how to add Cancel functionality to my form last night in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090203/how-do-i-cancel-a-create-or-edit-via-a-button-on-the-form/75091244#75091244) and got a couple of answers that work. However, it struck me that there might be another way to do it, namely having **both** buttons invoke the create() method of the controller and then for the create() method to determine which button was pushed, then do different logic based on which button was pressed. I'm imagining a session variable being set to "create" if the Create button is clicked and for the session variable to be set to "cancel" if the Cancel button is clicked.

If the Cancel button was pressed, the create() method would bypass validations and then redirect back to the index page with the message "Create() cancelled"; otherwise, if the Create button was pressed, the create() method would do all the validations, add the new record to the database, and then redirect to the index page with the message "Create was successful".

I have no concerns about getting the create() method to work but I'm having a challenge setting a session variable in my create template based on which button was pressed. I've tried several variations but all of them return "Cancel" REGARDLESS of which button was pressed! I don't understand this behaviour at all: clearly, Laravel doesn't work in the way that I imagine.

I researched how to set a session variable in a blade file here at StackOverflow but couldn't see any examples where the value of the variable was set conditionally so I clearly need some help with that part.

Here's my latest attempt at the template:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-card xclass="p-10 max-w-lg mx-auto mt-24">
    <h1 class="text-3xl text-center text-white font-bold bg-indigo-700">Create a New Non-driving Reason</h1>
    <h1 class="pb-5"></h1><!-- spacer beneath title -->
    
    <form method="POST" action="/nonDrivingReasons/store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <div class="mb-6">
            <label for="reason_for_not_driving" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Reason for not driving</label>
            <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="reason_for_not_driving" value="{{old('reason_for_not_driving')}}"/>
            @error('reason_for_not_driving')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
            @enderror
        </div>            
        <div class="mb-6">
            {{-- Submit the completed form --}}
            <button class="text-xl text-white bg-green-500 rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black" onClick="@php session()->put('button', 'submit') @endphp">Submit</button>
            {{-- Cancel submission of the form --}}
            <button class="text-xl text-white bg-black rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-red-300" onClick="@php session()->put('button', 'cancel') @endphp">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
    </form>
    </x-card>
    </x-layout>
```

Comment: Ok? Why do you want to use session? Will the data being pushed into the session overwrite any other data used by other forms? Is it genuinely obsolete to maintain the state of this session for other forms? or other parts of the site? If not, using a session would not be my first choice. Should `Cancel` just do what it says it does? Cancel (terminate) the forms appearance where you don't want to fill out the form? Or is Cancel an action your backend needs to know about to determine the call to action?

Comment: I am also very confused. If you want to cancel = "delete" or "discard" everything, then the second button should be redirected on click to another URL (I would use JS to achieve this), else, it is a normal button that pushes the process forward. Also, imagine if you have this on a Vue/React frontend, you have no session at all (at this instance), so I would also not use sessions as @dbf is also saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set session like this `onClick="@php session()->put('button', 'submit') @endphp"` because, php is server side scripting language and javascript is clientside, SO I suggest you to use little bit of js code instead of setting session,

Try using button as below:

```
            <button class="text-xl text-white bg-green-500 rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black" type="button">Submit</button>
        {{-- Cancel submission of the form --}}
        <button class="text-xl text-white bg-black rounded-md py-2 px-4 hover:bg-red-300" type="button" >Cancel</button>
                    </div>
```

And this small piece of javascript which help you to send which button you have clicked on the request:

```
<script>
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    document.getElementById("button").value = e.target.innerText;
    document.querySelector('form').submit()
});
```

so in Controller if you do `dd($request->button);` you can get the value text of button that you have clicked.

Comment: Thank you! I had hoped to find a solution that was entirely PHP but I'll give you the points because your answer WOULD accomplish what I'm asking.